# Adding list from controller class to a form list box

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi there I have a problem that I am currently stuck with. I'm trying to get myA list to show in my list box in my managing accounts from but when I run the program nothing shows up in the list box.

Here is my controller class, it hold a method to MakeAccounts() and AddAccounts()

```
// Methods for handling accounts

    public void MakeAccounts()
    {
        myA.Add(new Account.Everyday());
        myA.Add(new Account.Investment(5, 10));
        myA.Add(new Account.Omni(5, 10, -100));

        myA[0].Balance = 50;
        myA[1].Balance = 500;
        myA[2].Balance = 5000;

      //  WriteBinaryData();
    }
```

Here is my Manage Accounts From class, it has a DisplayAccounts() method which I have called in the Initialize Component part.

```
 private void DisplayAccounts()
    {
        listBoxManageAccounts.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Account account in control.myA)                        
        {
            listBoxManageAccounts.Items.Add(account);
        }
        if (listBoxManageAccounts.Items.Count >= 1)
        {
            listBoxManageAccounts.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Here is my account class:

```
 public class Account
 {
    static int nextAccountID = 1;
    protected int accountID;
    protected string typeName;
    protected decimal balance;
    protected string lastTransaction;

    public Account()
    {
        accountID = nextAccountID;
        nextAccountID++;
        balance = 0;
        lastTransaction = "There are no transactions.";
    }


    public decimal Balance
    {
        get { return balance; }
        set { balance = value; }
    }

   // public int Interest
   // {
   //     set { Interest = 4; }
   // }


    public class Everyday : Account
    {
        public Everyday()
        {
            typeName = "Everyday";
        }
    }

    public class Investment : Account
    {
        protected decimal interestRate;
        protected decimal failedTransFee;

        public Investment(decimal newInterestRate, decimal newFailedTransFee)
        {
            typeName = "Investment";
            interestRate = newInterestRate;
            failedTransFee = newFailedTransFee;
        }

    }

    public class Omni : Account
    {
        protected decimal interestRate;
        protected decimal failedTransFee;
        protected decimal overdraftLimit;

        public Omni(decimal newInterestRate, decimal newFailedTransFee, decimal newOverdraftLimit)
        {
            typeName = "Omni";
            interestRate = newInterestRate;
            failedTransFee = newFailedTransFee;
            overdraftLimit = newOverdraftLimit;
        }

    }
}
```

So what I want to happen is when this form is opened up I want the accounts (everyday, investment, omni) to appear in the list box straight away. Currently when I open this form nothing happens. Can anyone please tell me what's happening or where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Do you see items in control.myA?

Comment: @viveknuna No no items appear in the list box

Comment: It should be obvious that we would need to see the `Account` control class. I assume `myA` is a `List` of some kind but this is unclear. And what does the `AddAcount` have to do with this? If none of the data shows in the `ListBox`, then adding new items is a secondary (unrelated) problem. Please [edit] your question to provide more details as to the structure of `Account`… and is there some reason you do not set the list boxes `DataSource` as opposed to manually adding the items?

Comment: @DJDog it means your method to add items to list not getting called

Comment: @viveknuna why wouldn't it not being called?

Comment: @JohnG sorry that AddAccount() is for another part of my program ill delete it now.

Comment: Where is the `Account` class?

Comment: Sorry @JohnG added the account class now

Comment: Well… considering that you are not seeing “anything” in the `ListBox`, then we can only assume that `control.myA` contains no Accounts. Put a breakpoint on the line… `foreach (Account account in control.myA)` … when the code stops at the break point… examine `control.myA` to see what it contains. In other words, even in its current state, if `control.myA` truly contains items, then you should “see” something in the list box. Granted probably not what you want to display but “something” should be there.

Comment: What is `control`? What is `myA` ? and how is the posted code adding the items to `control.myA`? In the posted code, `myA` looks like a “separate” collection and is not necessarily associated with any particular `control` object. Again, it should be obvious that this info would be needed. Can you provide that code or elaborate on what these variables are? In my small tests, such that `myA` is a `List<Account>`… then the items class name at least displayed in the list box. I suggest you add an overridden `ToString` method to the `Account` class to output the values you want in the list box.